# how can i fix this errors in android studio?

Tags: android

So whenever i create new project in Android Studio this happens:
there is 4 errors in activity_main.xml and 6 errors in AndroidManifest.xml

this is activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
`android:layout_width="match_parent"`    <---ERROR(attribute android:layout_width is not allowed here)
`android:layout_height="match_parent"`    <---ERROR(attribute android:layout_height is not allowed )
`tools:context=".MainActivity">`      <---ERROR(attribute tools:context is not allowed here)

`<TextView`    <---ERROR(attribute TextView is not allowed here)


    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is Mainfest

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"<--ERROR(attribute android:allowBackup is not allowed here)
`android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`  <--ERROR(attribute android:icon is not allowed here)
android:label="@string/app_name"
`android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` <--ERROR(attribute android:roundIcon is not ...)
`android:supportsRtl="true"`  <--ERROR(attribute android:supportsRtl is not ...)
`android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`  <--ERROR(attribute android:theme is not allowed..)
    `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">` <--ERROR(Unresolved class MainActivity)


     <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes from your activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you removed them from AndroidManifest.xml too ? What is the error message ?

Comment: sory i dont get it. what i have to remove from androidmainfest.xml ? or from activity_main.xml

Comment: Remove all the symbols `

Comment: if in word symbols u mean words that are write in this "(here) "

Comment: i remove every symbol from activity_main and from rom mainfest as well

Comment: @nikaomadze so what are the new errors now, after fixing the issue?

Comment: it still saying that attribute andorid:layout is not allowed there andalso TextView

Comment: What happens when you replace the content of your activity_main.xml file with my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enable embedded Maven repository. To do it follow this path:

> File -> settings ->Build,Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Android Studio

and finally check Enable embedded Maven repository

> Good luck new contributor ;)

Comment: i get  only to Gradle after that there is only Runner file. there is no Android Studio. what to do ?

Comment: you can not find this path in android studio?what version of android studio do u use?